# Allocate ID to Fabric Object

Tags: fabricjs

I got number of polygons that i created on canvas as part of a test.
Now i am trying to figure out if its possible on polygon creation to set an ID of some sorts so that i can reference it later on.

my polygon creation code is as follows:

javascript

```
var polygon = new fabric.Polygon(coords, {
    fill: 'purple',
    selectable: true,
    lockMovementX: true,
    lockMovementY: true 
  });
  canvas.add(polygon);
```

If it is possible to set and identifier to the object how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here I have sample fiddle. I hope it will help you.
```

`Fiddle:`https://jsfiddle.net/mullainathan/pwmegjmk/

Comment: Please don't provide just a link. Your answer should be self-explanatory. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer